# Is there any way to create masonary js style in diamond shape?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create diamond shaped gallery design using html, Css and Jquery.
For creating diamond shaped design i used Diamond Js plugin. But all the diamond shapes are in equal size when i use this plugin. What i need is a combination of masonary plugin(https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html) and diamonds-js(http://mqchen.github.io/jquery.diamonds.js/) pluign for creating gallery with variable width and height as per the design attached in the below link.

**masonary design image**

[image: masonary design image]
Is there any way to create a structure like this?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is demo for what you are looking for:-

```js
$grid = $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: 75
    });
```

```css
#gallery {
  height: 400px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
#gallery .grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
#gallery .grid .grid-item {
  width: 75px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  height: 75px;
}
#gallery .grid .grid-item-width2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
#gallery .grid .grid-item-width3 {
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.1.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>

<div id="gallery">
 <div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried the above solution. In the above solution the whole wrapper is rotated.as a result some images gets cutoff.